# How can I implement polymorphism in this case with adding object to dictionary?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, polymorphism

Class Child implements Parent:

```
Child : Parent{}
```

I can add Child object to Parent list.

```
List<Parent> var = new List<Parent>();

var.Add(new Child());
```

But how can I add this list of Child into this Dictionary?

```
Dictionary<string, List<Parent>> var = new Dictionary<string, List<Parent>>();

var.Add("string", new List<Child>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `List<Child>` is a completely different type to `Child`. The fact the generic type used in the `List<T>` is `Child` is irrelevant. A `Dictionary<string, Child>` contains string keys and child objects. Is a `List<Child>` a child? No. So how would that work?

Answer (score 0):

A `List<Child>` cannot be assigned to a `List<Parent>` variable. They are unrelated types. Here's a "proof" by contradiction.

Suppose `List<Child>` can be assigned to `List<Parent>`, then this would be allowed by the compiler:

```
List<Parent> parents = new List<Child>();
parents.Add(new Child2()); // Child2 is another subclass of "Parent"
```

However, this creates a contradiction. `parents` actually stores a `List<Child>`, which is not capable of storing `Child2` objects.

---

A workaround you can use here is to create a `List<Parent>` object, and add your `Child` objects into that list:

```
var.Add("string", new List<Parent>());
List<Child> children = new List<Child> { ... }
var["string"].AddRange(children);
```